# Pad equality/identity (==/===) with whitespace if necessary (vim)

Tags: javascript, regex, vim

If there exists a tool to automatically prettify my js code then I would much rather use that package.

I want to expand everything such that a statement like this:

```
var n=x+(y+(z/k))-123;
```

turns into:

```
var n = x + (y + (z / k)) - 123;
```

However, for the moment, I want to convert all my cramped `=`, `==`, and `===`, statements into padded versions of themselves.

I tried using something like `:%s/[^ ]==[^ ]/ == /g` but the problem with that is that it clips the preceeding and proceeding character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Vim, you could use something like:

```
:%s!\s*\([!<>=/*+-]\+\)\s*! \1 !g
```

Explanation:

- `s` - substitute
- `!` - start pattern
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace
- `\(` - start group
- `[!<>=/*+-]\+` - one or more of `!<>=/*+-`
- `\)` - end of group
- `\s*` zero or more whitespace
- `!` end of pattern, beginning of replacement
- `<space>\1<space>` - the matched group padded by space
- `!` - End of replacement
- `g` - globally on a line

But if you want to prettify code and stick to a defined coding standard, you're better off using a tool like [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: This looks like it may work better then what I've got, +1 to you sir!

Comment: Also thanks for the link I'll check it out. I am currently trying out jsbeautify.

Comment: @chown: I've updated my answer to include !=, >=, <=, etc..., thanks to you :-)

Answer (score 2):

It would take multiple commands, but you could try something like:

```
:%s/\([^\s]\)\([+\/()-=]\)/\1 \2/g
:%s/\([+\/()-=]\)\([^\s]\)/\1 \2/g

:%s/\([^\s]\)==/\1 ==/g
:%s/==\([^\s]\)/== \1/g

Then do those last 2 for each: !=, >=, <=, etc..
```